# Retrieving array in GraphQL and Apollo

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, graphql, apollo

So I have set up an api using Graphql and apollo and have managed to get an array of strings into mongoDB ... now I am querying the data into react using Apollo and cannot seem to find how to retrieve it as I get a

```
error:[GraphQL error]: Message: String cannot represent an array value: [pushups,situps], Location: [object Object], Path: wods,0,movements
```

My schema is set up as :

```
   const WodType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Wod',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    movements: { type: GraphQLString },
    difficulty: { type: GraphQLString },
    group: {
  type: GroupType,
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return Group.findById(parent.groupId);
  }
}
```

})
});

and my mutation as:

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    addWod: {
      type: WodType,
  args: {
    name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    movements: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
    difficulty: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    groupId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
  },
  resolve(parent, args) {
    let wod = new Wod({
      // Use model to create new Wod
      name: args.name,
      movements: args.movements,
      difficulty: args.difficulty,
      groupId: args.groupId
    });
    // Save to database
    return wod.save();
  }
```

The array is an array of strings under "movements"... any help with the querying to get this into React is greatly appreciated ... here is the current query on the front end...using Apollo Boost

```
const getWodsQuery = gql`
  {
    wods {
      id
     name
      movements
      difficulty
    }
   }
 `;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is still relevant, i have not recreated the code, but the issue will probably be, that you are returning "movements" as just "string", not array of strings in output object type Wod. This is only assumption made based on the arguments that you are passing into mutation (which is the list of strings). The fix should be just to modify the Wood type as follows

```
const WodType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Wod',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    movements: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
    difficulty: { type: GraphQLString },
    group: {
  type: GroupType,
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return Group.findById(parent.groupId);
  }
})
```

Please note, that this is only assumption from me as i do not know how your data are stored, but it is probably correct based on the error message. I made the article on implementing lists/arrays in GraphQL schema as I saw that many people struggle with similar issues. You can check it out here https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/graphql-list-how-to-use-arrays-in-graphql-schema